# Kotlin pattern construction with different parameters

Tags: design-patterns, kotlin

Here is my dilemma.

1) I want to create instances of different classes depending on a single parameter --> **Solution : Factory Pattern**. The nice thing about Factory is zero parameter constructor.

2) Each of these classes have different constructors. 
For example

```
class PhotosProviderFacebook(val refActivity: WeakReference<Activity>)

class PhotosProviderLocal(val context: Context, val loaderManager: LoaderManager)
```

I thought about **Builder Pattern**. [See how Builder pattern is done in Kotlin](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-builder-pattern)

**Is there a design pattern that respect these constraints ?**

1) First build an instance depending on a parameter. Possibly without passing yet the constructor inputs.

2) Pass parameters in constructor

Factory + Builder are just an idea. Maybe there is a simpler way.

Comment: Consider static factory methods, would look rather clean.

Answer (score 3):

You probably might want to use a *strategy pattern* in combination with good old *polymorfism*

First, you can add an abstract class to your concrete classes

```
abstract class PhotosProvider

class PhotosProviderFacebook(val params: CreationParamsFacebook): PhotosProvider()

class PhotosProviderLocal(val params: CreationParamsLocal): PhotosProvider()
```

Then, you can do the same for the parameters, that may change depending on the class (I used Strings instead of your classes for simplicity and to make it compile)

```
abstract class CreationParams

class CreationParamsFacebook(val refActivity: String): CreationParams()

class CreationParamsLocal(val context: String, val loaderManager: String): CreationParams()
```

Now, I code the strategy pattern for each creation method (see how I can safely cast to the correct parameters for each class with *as*)

```
abstract class PhotosProviderCreationStrategy {
    abstract fun create(params: CreationParams) : PhotosProvider
}

class PhotosProviderFacebookCreationStrategy: PhotosProviderCreationStrategy() {
    override fun create(params: CreationParams): PhotosProvider {
        return PhotosProviderFacebook(params as CreationParamsFacebook)
    }
}

class PhotosProviderLocalCreationStrategy: PhotosProviderCreationStrategy() {
    override fun create(params: CreationParams): PhotosProvider {
        return PhotosProviderLocal(params as CreationParamsLocal)
    }
}
```

Finally, in order to redirect to the correct strategy I use a map with a specific type. You may also create an abstration that includes the type and the abstract params (which can be easily be converted with *Jackson* if you receive the date from a web service)

```
enum class CreationType {
    FACEBOOK_PROVIDER, LOCAL_PROVIDER
}

class PhotosProviderCreator(
    private val strategies: HashMap<CreationType, PhotosProviderCreationStrategy> = hashMapOf(
        CreationType.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER to PhotosProviderFacebookCreationStrategy(),
        CreationType.LOCAL_PROVIDER to PhotosProviderLocalCreationStrategy())
) {
    fun create(creationType: CreationType, creationParams: CreationParams): PhotosProvider {
        return strategies[creationType]?.create(creationParams)?: 
        throw RuntimeException("Strategy not found for type: $creationType")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation.
So the class `CreationParams` and childs contains the constructor params without being a `data class`. EDIT: childs of  `CreationParams` can be data class. But  `CreationParams` cannot be  a data class.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the children can be data classes

Comment: The Kotlin way to express multiple possibilities is to use sealed classes rather than abstract classes with enums.

Comment: Yes George, but there is no flexibility in the parameters for each class to be constructed. On the question, Raymond has different classes with different parameters.

Comment: @SebaD'Agostino, I added an elaboration of my comment in my answer.

Comment: It looks better now George. I also use this a lot, so I have to try it.

Answer (score 2):

This question reminds me [a talk](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/fppatterns/) on how the GoF design patterns are implemented in a functional language.

Yes, the answer is "with functions".

---

In the coroutines library, there is the type `Channel` and the function `Channel`.

```
public fun <E> Channel(capacity: Int = RENDEZVOUS): Channel<E> =
    when (capacity) {
        RENDEZVOUS -> RendezvousChannel()
        UNLIMITED -> LinkedListChannel()
        CONFLATED -> ConflatedChannel()
        else -> ArrayChannel(capacity)
    }
```

In Kotlin, object construction does not need the `new` keyword. So the invocations of this function looks just like using a constructor. Constructors for different `XyzChannel`s are called in the body of the `Channel` function.

---

You said "I want to create instances of different classes depending on a single parameter", and the above function does exactly the same thing. It may not be a good idea for *your* function to start with a uppercase letter though.

---

But the question remains, how does one pass different types of parameters to the function? The answer is to wrap them using subclasses of a same superclass.

This will be similar to the other answer, but utilizes one great feature of Kotlin – [sealed types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html).<sup>1</sup>

```
sealed class CreationParams
class PhotosProviderFacebookParams(val refActivity: WeakReference<Activity>) : CreationParams()
class PhotosProviderLocal(val context: Context, val loaderManager: LoaderManager) : CreationParams()

fun create(params: CreationParams) = when (params) {
    is CreationParamsFacebook -> PhotosProviderFacebook(params.refActivity)
    is CreationParamsLocal -> PhotosProviderLocal(params.contex, params.loadManager)
}
```

Since the class is `sealed`, the compiler can check for exhaustiveness, there is no need for an extra `enum`.<sup>2</sup>
There is also no manual type casting. The compiler [does it for you](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts).

---

1. The `sealed` types comes from the sum types of the [algebraic data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type), an idea that comes from the 70s. It is rather sad to see it became mainstream only recently.
2. Interestingly, in Swift, the same concept is [just enum](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#ID148).